# How to use ContextMenu on long click on the screen(on tablelayout for which parentlayout is scrollview)?

Tags: android

How to use ContextMenu on long click on the screen(on tablelayout for which parentlayout is scrollview)?

I have used scrollview within which i used tablelayout and on longclicking the that i need to display contextmenu.

On longclick i am able to display a toast but not the contextmenu. Within the OnLongClick() method i am not able to implement onCreateContextMenu() and onCreateContextMenu() methods.

Can anybody please me in this regard??If so I will be thankful to u...Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be useful, but I am guessing you are defining and OnLongClickListener inline with something like this

```
OnCreate
{

     TableLayout t = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.myTable)
     t.setOnLongclickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
     {
         void OnLongClick(View v)
         {
               //here is where I think you're trying to make a contextmenu
         }
     }

}
```

If I'm right, then because you're trying to make the context menu from an inner class, you need to reference your outer class. So you would need to call:

```
 [nameofyourclass].this.onCreateContextMenu(.....)
```